# HDD connected via USB cable - Disk unknown not initialized

Tags: hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive

I am using laptop with windows 8. I have connected my HDD [via USB cable](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/USB-2-0-to-SATA-Serial-ATA-22P-Adapter-Cable-For-2-5-HDD-SSD-Laptop-Hard-Drive/331223638497?_trksid=p2047675.c100005.m1851&_trkparms=aid%3D222007%26algo%3DSIC.MBE%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D29272%26meid%3D8c0260d06dca4c78a32a26b33e2c7482%26pid%3D100005%26rk%3D3%26rkt%3D6%26mehot%3Dpp%26sd%3D261644467925&rt=nc&tfrom=261644467925&tpos=unknow&ttype=price&talgo=origal). There are two lights on cable 'Access' and 'Power' access is glowing bright red and power dim red. When I connect HDD system detects it but when I go to disk management to activate it it shows following (Disk 2).

[image]

I have also tried connecting it to Windows 7 PC, again it would detect that something is connected but disk wouldn't appear under drives.

HDD is WD2000 (Western Digital 200GB), and I know t works (worked a year ago when I have pulled it out to use as archive, hasn't been dropped, was sitting cosy on a shelf). Another thing worth mentioning that drive is `MBR`, while both systems I have used to connect to use `UEFI` and `GPD`.

**I have read that it could be that USB port is lacking power and this is the reason why drive does not work? Or this is something else?**

Comment: Could be a power issue. Try a powered USB hub and see.

Comment: There might be a problem with the not supplying enough power via this cable. Try connecting the drive via SATA, as this will exclude any possible issues with USB drivers and power. You can also run the Quick test from the WD DLG tool: http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=dfUClZ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are wondering it was indeed 'lack of power' issue. Initially I was using [this cable](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/USB-2-0-to-SATA-Serial-ATA-22P-Adapter-Cable-For-2-5-HDD-SSD-Laptop-Hard-Drive/331223638497?_trksid=p2047675.c100005.m1851&_trkparms=aid%3D222007%26algo%3DSIC.MBE%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D29272%26meid%3D8c0260d06dca4c78a32a26b33e2c7482%26pid%3D100005%26rk%3D3%26rkt%3D6%26mehot%3Dpp%26sd%3D261644467925&rt=nc&tfrom=261644467925&tpos=unknow&ttype=price&talgo=origal) and it would detect that something was connected but could not reach the files, so I [got a powered one](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/320705061202?_trksid=p2060353.m2749.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT) and bingo.

[image]