# trying to repair laptop hard drive - Disk unknown not initialized

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

My buddy's laptop went on the fritz and I am repair detail.  I loaded the laptop drive in a Sabrent hard drive enclosure and tried to read it from another machine but in drive management it is saying "Disk 1 Unknown Not Initialized".  I loaded a fresh drive into the enclosure and it showed up fine so I know my machine I'm reading it from and the enclosure are working okay.

What can I do to try to fix it?

I've read some other issues like [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/924179/hdd-connected-via-usb-cable-disk-unknown-not-initialized#).  The next thing I was going to try was to throw it in freezer, as suggested by [ifixit](https://www.ifixit.com/Wiki/Hard_Drive_Troubleshooting)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like the drive is dead.  It could be a mechanical problem or a PCB problem.

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking that is probably the case. The drive is rather old, at least 7 years. Despite that my friend didn't really back up everything, so I'm still trying to save some of the data. Like I said, I think I'll try the freezer trick, then call it a day.